# Filtering list items by the first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul with list items. I am trying to filter out the items displayed by their first letter.

Filter the list:

```
<ul class="myFilters">
<li data-type="A">A</li>
<li data-type="B">B</li>
<li>etc...</li>
</ul>
```

The list

```
<ul class="myFilterItems">
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Banana</li>
<li>etc...</li>
</ul>
```

Ideally clicking on a `li` in `.myFilters` would show only the items in `.myFilterItems` that start with that letter.

Comment: jQuery has a `.filter()` method that iterates the elements, and includes/excludes them based on the return value of the callback. Just keep ones where the first letter of `.text()` doesn't match the clicked one, and do a `.hide()` on the resulting set. See the [docs for `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to find out how to use it.

Comment: Bind a `click` handler to the `.myFilters` `<li>` elements (or delegate it). Get the inner text. Then loop through all the items (however you want - `.each()`, `.filter()`, etc.)...get the text inside and compare the first character to the original letter. If they match, call `.show()`, otherwise call `.hide()`

Comment: `.myFilters` and `.myFilterItems` should really be [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors)s instead of a classes, they are specific items on the page, not types of things. In addition to semantics reasons, id selectors are much faster than class selectors when it comes to both CSS and JavaScript selector engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try something along the lines of this

```js
$('.myFilters li').click(function(){
   var v = $(this).text()[0]
   $('.myFilterItems li').hide().filter(function(){
      return $(this).text().toUpperCase()[0] == v;
   }).show()
})
```

Comment: While this is nice and usually the style I use, it's kind of inefficient - it ends up looping through elements 3 times. The first is for `.hide()`, internally looping to hide all of them. The second is for `.filter()`, explicitly looping for you to filter elements. And the third is for `.show()`, internally looping to show the elements matched.

Comment: Yes you're right :) This will have to be replace with `$('.myFilterItems li').each(function(){})` once the optimization guys get hold of the code ;)

Comment: @Ejay Again, I like this, I just wanted to point it out :)

Comment: @NathanPope thanks :). Ian, thanks for pointing out and adding useful information to this page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
$('.myFilters li').on("click", function() {
  var letter = $(this).text()[0];
  $('.myFilterItems li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text()[0] == letter) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

  });
});
```

You may want to deal with case senitivity (s or S), etc, but this should work...

Comment: That's scary similar to what i wrote, and you did post it first, so +1 to you.

Comment: var letter = $(this).data('type'); ???

Comment: How does `$(this).data('type')` get the letter? - use `$(this).text()`. And why are you using `.html()` later? - use `.text()`. Instead of `[0]`, you should use `.charAt(0)`

Comment: I was working from memory and thought the letter was in the data field..  Why have that anyways?    I've fixed this..

Comment: You still shouldn't use `[0]` to get a character of a string...use `.charAt(0)`

Comment: @Ian - jQuery does'nt even support that old versions of IE anymore, so who cares ?

Comment: Old IE is dead, give it up..

Comment: @adeneo Just because 2.0 doesn't, doesn't mean 1.9 isn't being supported anymore.

Comment: @Ian - but still, IE7, who uses that ?

Comment: @adeneo But still, why not use a method that **always** works everywhere and semantically makes more sense?

Comment: Another suggestion - you might want to compare the letters in a case-insensitive way, like changing both with `.toLowerCase()` - that may or may not be a concern of the OP though

Comment: @ Stephen - You're right I should have entered the character into the data field. That's what I meant to do initially I will edit that and place it in.

Comment: Arguing that its synatically clearer makes sense.  But you wouldn't argue that we need to still support Netscape 3... where do you draw the line...

Comment: @Stephen My main argument is what I already said: it works everywhere, so why not use it? You don't know what browser the user is using, or what version of jQuery the OP is using, so why not use the way that's universally compatible anyways?

Comment: @adeneo - LOTS of people still use IE7 . . . shoot, I had a client asked me to write code supported by IE5.5 last year.  Just because we don't like to support them, doesn't mean that we don't have to sometimes.