# filter list string based on first character in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am using msdropdown jquery. in this, it will filter the li string based on we type. but it search the li string which contains the given search text.
search is based on following code:

```
var items = $("#" + childid + " li:Contains('" + sText + "')").show();
```

but I need that if I type letter N, it should jump to the list which `li` have the index of N.

For example, I have a list "apple,banana, cake,dog,elephant,orange,ball,cat,doll,egg".

If I type "e", now it will filter the list as "apple,cake,elephant,orange"

but I need a filter like: "elephant,egg" like this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364815/filtering-list-items-by-the-first-letter

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector that simulates :starts-with or :ends-with for searching text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213907/jquery-selector-that-simulates-starts-with-or-ends-with-for-searching-text)